# Gradient ignores parent rounded shape

Tags: qt, qml, gradient, rectangles

I am trying to create a circle with a gradient color inside.  The rectangle with radius below works fine, but as soon as I added the RadialGradient it goes back to square shape.  I tried adding an opacity mask but it didn't work.  What's wrong with this?

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: light
    property string type: ""
    property bool connected: false
    property bool flagSet: false

    width: 50
    height: width
    radius: width / 2


    RadialGradient {
        anchors.fill: parent
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "green" }
            GradientStop { position: 0.5; color: "black" }
        }
    }


    OpacityMask {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: light
        maskSource: Rectangle {
            height: light.height
            width: light.width
            radius: light.radius
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
    Rectangle {
        id: border

        width: light.width + 2
        height: width
        radius: width / 2
        color: "red"

        RadialGradient {
            id: light
            anchors.centerIn: parent

            width: 50
            height: width

            gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "green" }
                GradientStop { position: 0.5; color: "black" }
            }

            layer.enabled: true
            layer.effect: OpacityMask {
                id: mask
                maskSource: Rectangle {
                    height: light.height
                    width: light.width
                    radius: width / 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That works well - but - I had planned to add 1 pixel border around the circle (that's why I chose the rectange).  Is that possible with just RadialGradient?

Comment: I added back in the parent rectangle as a border.

Comment: I think I get it now.  I also tried layering a transparent rectangle with border on top of the gradient - either works